# R - Function: Logical Transformation of Data?

Tags: r

I am trying to have some data logit transformed based on a given part of the function. Here is my code:

```
plot_cp <- function(est, iso_code, logit_scale = FALSE){
  newdata <- fp.data %>% 
  filter(`ISO code` == iso_code, `Median estimate and uncertainty intervals` == "Median", Indicator == "CPmod", `Marital status` == "MW")
  logit_scale <- function(newdata){
  pmax(logit(0.01), logit(newdata))}
  ggplot(data = newdata) + geom_line(mapping = aes(Year, Percentage))
}
```

The logit() function that is not shown here is:

```
logit <- function(x){
  logprop <- log(x / (1 - x))
```

I am trying to have logit_scale do another function if it is set to TRUE, and nothing if it is left at its default (FALSE).

How should I go about this? I know it is an issue with my syntax. I am by no means fluent in the language of R, so I appreciate any help here.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you applying the `logit_scale` function that you define. It looks like you define `newdata`, you define `logit_scale()`, and then you plot based on `newdata` before any transformation is applied.

Comment: @JonSpring Thank you! I appreciate your help in this. It has helped me to better understand how these functions work.

Comment: Does adding the line `newdata <- if(logit_scale) { newdata %>% logit_scale}` before the ggplot line do what you want?

Comment: @JonSpring That did not work, but I appreciate your continued help! Honestly, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

You've used logit_scale to mean 2 different things. An argument of your function that decides which type of logit function to use, and a type of logit function.
You also need to use the function somewhere (as Jon Spring said)
See if this is what you want:

```
plot_cp <- function(est, iso_code, logit_scale = FALSE){
  newdata <- fp.data %>% 
    filter(`ISO code` == iso_code, `Median estimate and uncertainty intervals` == "Median", Indicator == "CPmod", `Marital status` == "MW")
  scaled_logit <- function(x){
    pmax(logit(0.01), logit(x))}
  my_logit <- if (logit_scale) scaled_logit else logit
  newdata$Logit <- my_logit(newdata$Percentage)
  ggplot(data = newdata) + geom_line(mapping = aes(Year, Logit))
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I needed (this does a logit transformation no matter what, it seems), but your explanation helped me to better understand the syntax of functions for R, so I really appreciate that!